# Special character from custom font is not displayed in HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts

My HTML is using custom font to display special symbols. There are a lot of symbols, but only one of them is not displayed. It has the code `00AD`

```html
    <table id="table_symbols">
        <tr>
            <td class="symbol">&#x00AD;</td>
            <td>Pair of bishops</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I've searched and found that this is a special code for the soft hyphen character in HTML, so looks like the character is not taken from the font, but replaced with soft hyphen.

Is there any way to forbid such replacement? Or it is easier to edit the font?

Comment: Try to add ```<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">``` in the head.

Comment: @aavrug this doesn't helps.

Comment: Can you try adding `hyphens: none` to your `symbol` class?

Comment: @DavidR Chrome tells `Unknown property name` on `hyphens`. And on `-webkit-hyphens` too.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `-webkit-hyphens`

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev Can you please post the css code of `symbol` class?

Comment: @DavidR #table_symbols .symbol { text-align: center; font-family: CAChessRegular; -webkit-hyphens: none; }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123434/discussion-between-david-r-and-artem-mostyaev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this:

http://unicode-table.com/en/00AD/
https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html

> The Unicode character 00AD is defined to be invisible, except at the
>   end of a line, where it may or may not be visible, depending on the
>   script.

Anyway what you used was not the html correct code, instead `&shy;` or `&#173;` are used in html.

Use this [**example**](http://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/mAPGEq) to understand the behavior of the ­ element; (Note resize slowly and watch as the text has hyphen on the end but on normal view there is not).

This is the trick I used when making design for Hiring ads and the client wants pure grammar and also justified effect with no inner spaces(languages like German have big words and if no hyphens words will spread apart when justified).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting info! But I need to display other symbol from my custom font instead of hyphen. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you add an image of that character?

Comment: Here is an example of HTML with the custom font - https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gvzfgwmsoz5s1v/symbols_convention.zip?dl=0. Symbols should look like two crossed rectangles, you can view it in .ttf.

Comment: If you want to replicate that for the sign that has meaning "Bishops of the same color", you need to use: &macr; . Use this site to check what caracter means what : http://unicodelookup.com/#¯/1 (Copy paste and search and see what code has the caracter).

Comment: The problem is that symbol "Pair of bishops" is not displayed. Can you share the html/css of what you proposing?

Comment: So for the first matter: do you have the font as a web font? ( .woff format), Second matter: Check if you have it imported correctly in css, cause if you go and just modify the character table page and add what I told you, you are getting the exact same thing.Check these first.

Comment: I doesn't have it as .woff. If I change the symbol code, it is displayed normal. The problem is only with code 173. So this is what the question is. Can I display own character with 173 code?

Comment: No, there are some standards that should be complied to. All the documentation and the standards are presented here: https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html.

Comment: Thank you! I understood.